# D3 SVG with finite height and width

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I want to create work space, in which have to use D3 SVG with fixed width and height. Normally, this svg is infinite in both dimensions. In below example, circle element is draggable upto any position(even outside) in viewport.

fiddle link:
    https://jsfiddle.net/313vhqdx/

```
var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                  .attr("id", "svgcontainer")
                  .attr("width", 300)
                  .attr("height", 300)
                  .style("background-color", "blue")
                  .call(zoom)
                .append("g");
```

But in my case, I need to set fixed width and height for SVG. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Do you want to stop the "zoom" action at a certain size?

Comment: Not to stop "zoom" action. Have to restrict the draggable action when we drag the element outside the viewport. It should be only draggable inside the viewport. - @ccprog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SVG itself always has conceptually infinite coordinates. But in d3 since version 4 you can easily restrict the zoom/drag with `zoom.translateExtent`:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .translateExtent([[-100, -100], [400, 400]])
    .scaleExtent([0, 2])
    .on("zoom", function () {
        container.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });
```

Since jsfiddle only loads d3 version 3, here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgwaQE).

Comment: This is what I needed. Currently I'm using D3 v3. Is there any possibility to achieve this by using jquery functionalities instead of replacing D3 v3 into v4? - @ccprog

Comment: That would have no benefits. jQuery does not support SVG properties the way d3 does. The core of what you will have to write is event listeners restricting transform values, and that is a pure JS and math task, anyway.

Comment: I can't understand how to give coordinate inside .translateExtend() method. Can you please tell me the purpose and how to give coordinates? - @ccprog

Comment: See the [API doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_translateExtent)

Comment: if [x0, y0] is the top-left corner of the world means, then why we are giving [-100, -100] instead of [0, 0]. If i give [0,0], then whole SVG dimension gets collapsed. @ccprog

Comment: Remember you are moving the `<svg id="svgcontainer">` element. The circle is smaller. To get it to the border of the clipping area, the contaainer has to move further out.

Comment: how to implement this in d3 v3?